# CSS & PHP with Grid Layout - dynamic data from mysql - creating heading for each group of rows

Tags: php, css, css-grid

I have grouped data coming back from mysql to a php and html page.  I have shown an example in the link below.  In some groups (trees) there will be 5 sub-items (varieties).

https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/ccgbr?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles= [1](http://%20https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/ccgbr?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=)

Updated link after comments with @AHaworth

```
https://phpsandbox.io/n/still-glade-omzr-mksqw
```

For other trees there will only be one or two varieties.
The link is to a working example; but I feel that conditional statements to control the display of the group is a workaround.  Is there a better way to use the power of CSS grid to position and format this as per this image:

[image: Desired Result with Tree Names and Varieties]
I think that one of the issues (or part of the solution!) might be to change the css class based on the number of sub-items (varieties).  Might this be possible by generating the class name like this:

```
<?php '<div class= "variety_row_' . $variety_row_count . '">' ?>
```

which might output `<div class= "variety_row_5">`
The maximum number of varieties might be say 10 so this is feasible.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like real tabular data to me, so why not lay it out as a table, two cells per row.

For example:

```css
.trees td:first-child {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.trees td:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="trees">
  <tr class="tree">
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>
      <div>Cox</div>
      <div>Crab</div>
      <div>Cooker</div>
      <div>Discovery</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Birch</td>
    <td>
      <div>Downy</div>
      <div>Silver</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Obviously there's more formatting you'll want to do to the two cell types.

UPDATE: we now have more information on the content, which has several more columns. This snippet takes the given code, moving it into table format, and putting the correct rowspan attribute into the cells of class type. [You could do this with the PHP instead of a class].

The other change that has been made is to set font-size to min(14px, 1.5vmin) to ensure that the text has a chance of being readable on narrow viewports.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: max(14px, 1.5vw);
}

table {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.activity {
  color: red;
}

.type {
  color: green;
}

.number {
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
}

.date {
  color: purple;
}

.id {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  /*grey*/
}

.description_short {
  color: blue;
}

.success {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0E6A00;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.error {
  color: white;
  background-color: #B95B5B;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.textarea {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="sub_wrapper">
    <td class="type" rowspan="4">
      Apple </td>

    <td class="description_short">
      Crab ~ sharp </td>
    <td class="number">
      75 </td>
    <td class="number">
      99 </td>
    <td class="date">
      2021-2-2 </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      three trees left - dangerous for livestock </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub_wrapper">
    <td class="description_short">
      Cooker ~ tart </td>
    <td class="number">
      50 </td>
    <td class="number">
      99 </td>
    <td class="date">
      2021-2-2 </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      three trees left - dangerous for livestock </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="sub_wrapper">
    <td class="description_short">
      Discovery ~ cruchy ~ delicious </td>
    <td class="number">
      25 </td>
    <td class="number">
      99 </td>
    <td class="date">
      2021-2-2 </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      three trees left - dangerous for livestock </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub_wrapper">
    <td class="description_short">
      Cox ~ sweet </td>
    <td class="number">
      50 </td>
    <td class="number">
      99 </td>
    <td class="date">
      2021-2-2 </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      three trees left - dangerous for livestock </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub_wrapper">
    <td class="type" rowspan="2">
      Birch </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      Silver ~ North_America </td>
    <td class="number">
      2 </td>
    <td class="number">
      99 </td>
    <td class="date">
      2021-2-2 </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      three trees left - dangerous for livestock </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub_wrapper">
    <td class="description_short">
      Downy ~ As described </td>
    <td class="number">
      4 </td>
    <td class="number">
      99 </td>
    <td class="date">
      2021-2-2 </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      three trees left - dangerous for livestock </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub_wrapper">
    <td class="type">
      Cedar </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      Cedar ~ Beautiful Smell </td>
    <td class="number">
      20 </td>
    <td class="number">
      99 </td>
    <td class="date">
      2021-2-2 </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      three trees left - dangerous for livestock </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub_wrapper">
    <td class="type" rowspan="2">
      Beech </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      Common ~ Escarpment specialist </td>
    <td class="number">
      123 </td>
    <td class="number">
      99 </td>
    <td class="date">
      2021-2-2 </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      three trees left - dangerous for livestock </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub_wrapper">
    <td class="description_short">
      Copper ~ Landmark </td>
    <td class="number">
      10 </td>
    <td class="number">
      99 </td>
    <td class="date">
      2021-2-2 </td>
    <td class="description_short">
      three trees left - dangerous for livestock </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you @AHaworth  I think this is where I would have started and I can see how this would work with the dynamic nature of data being drawn from mysql - but please see the link to phpsandbox  as part of the reason I was using <div> and grid was to make it responsive; and I think a table would not be so good at this?

Comment: I think your example is spot on (better than my image(!) but I would appreciate your thoughts about the transferability to smaller screens - thank you

Comment: Is there a problem with smaller screens? If the data is of the type you showed then it seems well suited to being in two columns. I guess you'd want to think about how large you wanted the font size to be if on a really small screen.

Comment: thinking about mobiles - perhaps.  But I guess I could use something like 
font-size: 1vw; in the CSS

Comment: apologies everyone - I should have put in full requirement up front.  Mistakenly I thought the example would demonstrate the principle
so - clarity is:
1) it has to be responsive
2) there will be several "columns" of data.  
The first column will be a "group" name
The second column will be text of varying length.  Usually 2 or 3 words
The third to 5th columns will be numbers - usually 2 digits and rarely 3
The 6th column will be date or time data
The 7th column will be comments of varying length
Hence my thought that Grid would be the most "responsive" way of doing this
Thank you

Comment: Could you put an example into your question. It sounds even more like tabular data to me so I'm not sure what the problem with having it set as a table is - semantically it might also be useful to do this for screen readers.

Comment: here is an updated link to the combined php and html   https://phpsandbox.io/n/still-glade-omzr-mksqw  
Perhaps I am taking too literally the statement "do not use tables in a responsive application ~ only use divs and CSS grid or flex"
@AHaworth Thank you

Comment: would it be better to put the code into the question itself rather than just the link?
it is 145 lines so cautious about TLDNR...
Really appreciative of yours and others time

Comment: I have taken your data from the sandbox and converted it to a table format in case of use. I don't understand the quote "do not use tables in a responsive application" - do you have a reference?

Comment: perfect @AHaworth - thank you - beyond the call of duty and appreciated.  
My "assumption" about tables and responsive design are based on conversation so no reference.  This exchange has led me to look closely at semantics and separating content and presentation.  I will start with your code above for this particular implementation and develpo further - thank you.

Comment: I think I can see where the comment might be coming from as in the 'old days' HTML table was used sometimes for layout, even when the content wasn't strictly tabular data and so is now frowned on. But of course if your data is in reality a table then HTML table is still the way to go if poss. Glad it helped.

Comment: I think your summary is on the nail  - and table definitely the way to go here - good learning thank you

Comment: if you have time to post your code as the answer (or not!) I will close the question and upvote the answer